# How to preselect item in Html.DropDownlListFor()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

How can i preselect item in Html.DromDownListFor() ?
i have code in view which inserts items to DropDownListFor

```
<div class="editor-field">
                <%var mesta = new List<SelectListItem>();
              SelectListItem aa = new SelectListItem();
              aa.Text = "---------VYBER MESTO---------";
              aa.Value = "0";
              mesta.Add(aa);
              foreach (var item in Model.MestoTbl)
              {
                  SelectListItem a = new SelectListItem();
                  a.Text = item.Mesto;
                  a.Value = item.MestoId.ToString();
                  mesta.Add(a);}%>
                <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Mesto.MestoId, mesta)%>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mesto.MestoId)%>
            </div>
```

this inserts 2 values MestoId & Mesto ....when i click on some database record (edit field)
example =>

```
Name  Surname Mesto
--------------------
Peter Malik   Snina
```

Snina => Mestoid = 2
I wanna get ....
if i click  to edit record of Peter Malik the Html.DropDownListFor automatically preselect item Snina in list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `SelectList` constructor. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist_members.aspx).

Comment: i will try but i am not sure that i wil know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

thanks now it is working.

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Mesto.MestoId, new SelectList(mesta, "Value", "Text", Model.Ziak.MestoId))%>
```